# React Native - Scheduling a background bluetooth scanning task as a Headless JS Service

Tags: android, react-native

Not sure if anyone would be able to help out, I have an application that scans and interacts with Bluetooth devices, the application works fine however I'd like to utilise [Headless JS background services](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android) so that the scanning and interactions work at all times.

The process which I'd like to replicate as a service does the following

- scans for Bluetooth devices
- when a device is found commands are sent and data is received
- the app processed the data and posts it up to the API
- the app continues to scan and wait for the next device

I'd like to know how I could manage such a service so that it complies with the following

- I would like to ensure the service is always running and there is only 1 instance of it running at any time.
- The service will need to be able to start straight away or start as soon as the app is out of memory(i.e. keep a foreground instance of the code running and switch to the background service once that's unreachable).

Any advice on how to set up the scheduling of services would definitely help out!